# mySQL table with {"Twitter": 28, "Total": 28, "Facebook": 1}

Tags: mysql

There is a table with one column, named "info", with content like `{"Twitter": 28, "Total": 28, "Facebook": 1}`. When I write sql, I want to test whether "Total" is larger than 10 or not. Could someone help me write the query? (table name is `landslides_7d`)

(this is what I have)

```
SELECT *  FROM landslides_7d WHERE info.Total > 10;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, when you say `I want to test`? Do you want a *list* of all rows where the `Total` is > 10? Or, a count of how many rows there are? Or, given a row, do you want a "true/false" value for whether the row matches this criteria?

Comment: I want a list of all rows where the Total is > 10

Comment: Your table must have at least 2 columns. Are you extracting the data through some sort of JSON tool or API generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are storing the JSON in a single blob or string column. This is very inefficient, since you can't make use of indexes, and will need to parse the entire JSON structure on every where query. I'm not sure how much flexibility you need, but if the JSON attributes are relatively fixed, I recommend running a script (ruby, Python, etc.) on the table contents and storing "total" in a traditional columnar format. For example, you could add a new column "total" which contains the total attribute as an INT.

A side benefit of using a script is that you can catch any improperly formatted JSON - something you can't do in a single query.

You can also keep "total" column maintained with a trigger (on update/insert of "info"), using the JSON_EXTRACT function referenced in @johannes answer.

Comment: If `JSON_EXTRACT` is available you're most likely on MySQL 5.7. Then you can use a generated column instead of a manual trigger which requires less storage (only the index is stored) and is reliable (the database understands the purpose)
http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/

Answer (score 1):

The data format seems to be JSON. If you have MySQL 5.7 you can use `JSON_EXTRACT` or the short form `->`. Those functions don't exist in older versions.

```
SELECT * FROM landslides_7d WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(info, '$.total') > 10;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM landslides_7d WHERE info->total > 10;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

Mind that this is a full table scan. On a "larger" table you want to create an index.

If you're on an older version of MySQL you should create an extra column to your table and manually add the total value to that column.